# list view with section header and selecting only one item from each section

Tags: android

I want to create listview with section headers. In each section user should be allowed to select  only one item . Can any one help me please how to implement this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this tutorial describes what you need:

http://bartinger.at/listview-with-sectionsseparators/

Comment: Thanks for your response. In this example can user select  one item from each section?